# Как обновить поля без смены id

Tags: android, sqlite3

Создаю 2 таблицы примерно следующей схемы:

```
"CREATE TABLE " + Product.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
        Product._ID  + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, " +
        Product.SEARCH_KEYWORD + " varchar(64) NOT NULL," +
        "UNIQUE  (" + Product.SEARCH_KEYWORD +  ")" +
        " )";


"CREATE TABLE " + Item.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
        Item._ID  + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, " +

        Item.PRODUCT_ID + " int(11), FOREIGN KEY("+ Item.PRODUCT_ID + ")REFERENCES " +
        Product.TABLE_NAME + "(" + Product._ID + ")" + "ON DELETE CASCADE " +
        "UNIQUE  (" + Item.KEYWORD + "," + Item.PLUGIN_TITLE + ")" +
        " )";
```

И теперь стоит задача обновлять данные с таблиц делая новый запрос на сервер. Если использовать `insertWithOnConflict` или модификатор `"ON CONFLICT REPLACE"`, то данные перезаписываются с новым `id` (что логично), а мне бы хотелось просто обновлять не уникальные поля новыми данными. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Что-то не совсем понимаю вашу проблему. Есть метод, который позволяет обновить поле таблицы 
`SQLiteDatabase.update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)`. [Ссылка на источник](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).

Comment: но это нужно сначала проверить сущестувет ли эта запись в таблице, что мне не очень нравиться

Comment: @Tany А зачем проверять? Если записи нет то просто ничего не произойдет, update вернет 0.

Comment: что бы потом сделать инсерт

Comment: А в чём проблема сделать update и если вернётся 0, то сделать insert, это не будет трудозатратно по ресурсам. Напрягайте голову, а то такое ощущение, что вы просто отказываетесь думать и ждёте ответа здесь

Comment: да нет, я ваш вариант реализовал еще до вопроса. А вопрос был задан для разширенние кругозора. Xотелось бы что то как в mysql "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"